# Trying to construct a function where partial derivatives are these particular functions. Am I correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, partial-derivative

I need a function $F$ of $(x,y)$ such that, for specific function $G$ of $(x,y)$, I have:

> $\partial F/\partial x=\partial G/\partial x$ and $\partial F/\partial y=0$.

How can I construct it?

I thinked about $F(x,y)=G(x,y)-G(0,y)+C,\qquad C$ constant... So,

$\partial F/\partial x=\partial G/\partial x\cdot 1-\partial G/\partial x\cdot 0=\partial G/\partial x$

and

$\partial F/\partial y=\partial G/\partial y\cdot 1-\partial G/\partial y\cdot 1=0$.

Am I correct?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is $G$ specified, or arbitrary? In general there's little hope of having such an $F$ with continuous second-order partials (can you see why?).

Comment: Is specified but I do not have much information. I know that $F$ exists because there's given. It's part of an article

Comment: @MarkS. Sorry, why did you say second-order?

Comment: If G is specified, this becomes a completely different problem. You can't do this in most usual cases because Clairaut's Theorem yields a contradiction unless $G$'s mixed second order partial is already $0$.

Comment: Right, is it because of answer bellow? And I'll explain a little bit more: I have by sure that the jacobian of a function $F=(F_1,F_2)$ is of form $\begin{bmatrix}\partial G/\partial x & 0 \\ 0 &\partial H/\partial y \end{bmatrix}$. So, can I get from this that $G$, $H$ satisfy what Paul Sinclair said and so $F(x,y)=(G_1(x),H_2(y))+C=(G(x,0),H(0,y))+C'$ (note that $G_2(0),H_1(0)$ are constants)? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it except in special circumstances.

Because $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$, we can hold $y$ constant and integrate with respect to $x$ to get $F(x,y) = G(x,y) + C_y$ where the constant term can change with $y$, which in fact makes it a function of $y$:
$$F(x,y) = G(x,y) + c(y)$$
Since both $F$ and $G$ are differentiable with respect to $y$, $c$ must be differentiable as well. Differentiating:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial y} + c'(y)$$
But $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 0$, so $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = -c'(y)$$
Integrating this equation with respect to $y$ gives
$$G(x,y) = -c(y) + d(x)$$

And therefore for such an $F$ to exist, it must be possible to express $G(x,y)$ as the sum of functions in $x$ and $y$:

$$G(x,y) = g_1(x) + g_2(y)$$

Most functions of two variables will not satisfy that condition. If $G$ does satisfy that condition, then $F(x,y) = g_1(x) + C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: Let me explain a little bit more: I have by sure that the jacobian of a function $F=(F_1,F_2)$ is of form $\begin{bmatrix}\partial G/\partial x & 0 \\ 0 &\partial H/\partial y \end{bmatrix}$. So, can I get from this that $G$, $H$ satisfy what you said and so $F(x,y)=(G_1(x),H_2(y))+C=(G(x,0),H(0,y))+C'$ (note that $G_2(0),H_1(0)$ are constants)? Many thanks!

Comment: That is a different condition. It just requires that $G$ is a function of $x$ only, and $H$ is a function of $y$ only, where $F(x,y) = (G(x), H(y))$.That is the only thing needed to meet the Jacobian condition.

Comment: But by the text $G$ is a function of $y$ as well (but the text does not say how). So can I recognize that $G$ has that separated form ($g_1(x)+g_2(y)$), what do you think? Many thanks once again.

Comment: The upper right element of the Jacobian is $\partial G/\partial y$. That value is $0$. That means that $G$ does not vary with $y$. This does *not* mean $G$ cannot be considered a function of both $x$ and $y$. What it means is that $G$ is constant with respect to $y$: If you fix a value of $x, G(x,y)$ will not change its value no matter what $y$ you put in. The same is true of $H$, except that it is constant with respect to $x$, not $y$.

Comment: I suppose my earlier wording led to the confusion. When $G$ is constant with respect to a variable, it is common to say that it is a function of the other variable only, since it only changes value when the other variable does. This doesn't mean you cannot even consider $G$ to be a function of $y$. In fact, you can consider $G$ to be a function of $y, z, t, w, ...$ and any other variables you desire. But its value is determined strictly by $x$.

Comment: First, many thanks for all atention. Second, I think I led to a confusion. Note that the upp right is not necessary $\partial G/\partial y $ it's $\partial F_1/\partial y $... right?

Comment: I mean, by the text $G$ is dependent of $y$ in really.

Comment: You have been using $G, H$ and $F_1, F_2$ in ways that have been confusing, but you will note that in my reply comment I specifically say that I am talking about. $F = (G, H)$, and that is what I've been using. So as far as I am concerned in these comments, $F_1 = G, F_2 = H$.

Comment: Right, I'll try explain, and I'm so sorry by the confusion. I opened a bounty to bounty you by your expansive attention, as a little form to thank you (sorry by the bounty so small, I do not have much rep yet). Well: $F=(F_1,F_2)$, and WE DO NOT HAVE anything give us that $F_1=G,F_2=H$, right? $G$ and $H$ are others functions of the article. However, I have that the Jacobian of $F$ is $\begin{bmatrix}\partial G/\partial x & 0 \\ 0 &\partial H/\partial y \end{bmatrix}$. So I'm trying to get $F_1,F_2$ in function of $G,H$. Do you understand? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't need a bounty. Rep is okay, but it is not why I do this.

Comment: OK, it's just a form to thank you once I do not know other form... Thank you. :) And the comment above is edited. Other information is that all functions are diferenciable.

Comment: Then we are back to this is only possible if $G = g_1(x) + g_2(y)$, and $H = h_1(x) + h_2(y)$. And in this case $F = (g_1(x) + C_1, h_2(y) + C_2)$ for some constants $C_1, C_2$. If either $G$ or $H$ is not representable as a sum of functions of each variable separately, then no $F$ can satisfy the condition.

Comment: And note that for a general function $G$, it is unlikely that $G(x, y) \ne G(x, 0) + G(0, y)$, so you cannot meet this condition easily. Most smooth functions of two variables cannot be represented as $g_1(x) + g_2(y)$. In fact, for twice-differentiable $G$, the condition is equivalent to $$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x\partial y} = 0$$.

Comment: Right, many thanks.